# How do I remove a specific size class preview in Xcode 6?

Tags: xcode6

In Xcode 6, I opened up the Preview so I could see how my storyboard would look on different devices.  I can add devices to the preview.  In fact, I can add the same device to the preview over and over.  But how do I remove a device from the preview?  I tried closing out of Xcode and re-opening it, but they are still there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know if I tried this in XCode 6.0 or not, but I'm on 6.1 now and I was able to remove the previewed device.  Select the device (you can see a blue outline around the device when selected) in the Preview panel then press delete.  That will remove it from the Preview panel.

Comment: That's true. Unfortunately it's not so intuitive that "delete" button is a hardware button on a keyboard.

Comment: For people with delete-less keyboards, it's fn+backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Kurt Anderson's answer works from Xcode 6.1 all the way to the latest Version 8.2.1 (8C1002).  I assume the same "select" then "delete" will  work for the future Xcode as well.