# How to delete a previewed device in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

As we know Xcode 6 provides a way to preview the layout of the storyboard in different devices at the same time. I know how to add a preview device, but how do I delete any of them? I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567839/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-size-class-preview-in-xcode-6), but still don't know where is the 'Preview panel' and cannot found the 'delete' button anywhere, anyone help? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Click on the X in the top-right corner.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen No, that'll close the whole panel instead of the selected device

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's actually the preview panel. To delete, select the preview layout that you don't want (Blue outline will appear around it) and just press the "Delete" button on your keyboard.

[image: Delete preview]

Comment: I feel like myself a dumbass when I see your answer, thanks anyway ;)